# Normal subgroups of dihedral groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In relation to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484502/geometric-interpretation-of-the-dihedral-subgroups-of-a-dihedral-group), I am curious about what exactly are the normal subgroups of a dihedral group $D_n$ of order $2n$.

It is easy to see that cyclic subgroups of $D_n$ is normal. But I suspect that case analysis is needed to decide whether dihedral subgroups of $D_n$ is normal.

A little bit of Internet search suggests the use of semidirect product $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z) \rtimes (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z) \cong D_n$, but I do not know the condition for subgroups of a semidirect product to be normal.

I would be grateful if you could suggest a way to enumerate the normal subgroups of $D_n$ that does not resort to too much of case analysis.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf) is a nice answer: the dihedral group is generated by a rotation $R$ and a reflection $F$ subject to the relations $R^n=F^2=1$ and $(RF)^2=1$.
For $n$ odd the normal subgroups are given by $D_n$ and $\langle R^d \rangle$ for all divisors $d\mid n$. If $n$ is even, there are two more normal subgroups, i.e., $\langle R^2,F \rangle$ and $\langle R^2,RF \rangle$.

Comment: You have lost track of the group $D_n$ itself.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Of course, the group itself should be included.

Comment: By saying $\langle{R^d}\rangle$ is a normal subgroup for all divisors $d\  \mid\  {n}$, you've actually already included {1}, because $n\   \mid\ {n}$.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde : Is there any other normal subgroups of $D_{2n}$ besides these normal subgroups

Comment: @user120386 No, this is a complete classification of normal subgroups, see Keith Conrad's article on [dihedral groups](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/dihedral2.pdf).

Comment: I'd like to prove that argument for some given $n$ and I understand that this answer provides a way to find normal subgroups of $D_n$ but how do you prove that this are the only subgroups of $D_n$?

Comment: @Jneven those are *not* the only subgroups of $D_n$: they are the only normal subgroups of $D_n$.  There are non-normal subgroups of $D_n$ as well, which are not included in the answer above, such as $\langle F\rangle = \{1,F\}$. At the link provided in the answer, Theorem 3.1 describes all subgroups of $D_n$ while Theorem 3.8 describes all normal subgroups of $D_n$.