# Interesting property of dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I know the number of normal subgroup in $D_3$ and $D_4$ but I don't know the number of normal subgroup of rest of the Dihedral group like $D_{16}$ or $D_{60}$.  I want to know is there any formula for finding number of normal subgroup in $D_n$.  If there is no formula for that then how could we able to find that as I'm a beginner please help.

Comment: duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/484828)