# What's the smallest normal subgroup of $D_{12}\times D_{12}$ that contains $(s,s)$ where $s$ is reflection?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What's the smallest normal subgroup of $D_{12}\times D_{12}$ that contains $(s,s)$ where $s$ is reflection?

My guess is $\langle s,r^2\rangle \times \langle s,r^2\rangle$  but I'm not too sure how to show it is the smallest. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know all normal subgroups of $D_n$, see

[Normal subgroups of dihedral groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484828/normal-subgroups-of-dihedral-groups)

it is clear that $\langle s,r^2\rangle$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $D_n$ containing $s$. Now [Goursat's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat%27s_lemma) describes normal subgroups in the direct product. This is also explained an MSE, e.g.,

[Subgroups of a direct product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485512/subgroups-of-a-direct-product)