# Does $D_{15}$, the dihedral group of order 30 have a normal subgroup of order 6?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This question is from Artin Algebra: List the proper normal subgroups N of the dihedral group $D_{15}$. I have most of the answer, partly from Takumi Murayama's solutions to Artin: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b01902113/artin-sols.pdf

Let $D_{15}= \{1,x, ..., x^{14}, y, yx, ... ,yx^{14}\}$, with the relations  $$x^{15} = 1, y^{2} = 1, yx = x^{14}y$$
The orders of the proper subgroups can be $2, 3, 5, 6, 15$. Every element of the form $x^{i}y$ generates an order $2$ subgroup, because $$x^{i}y*x^{i}y = x^{i}x^{14i}yy = x^{15i} = 1$$ These subgroups of order $2$ can't be normal, because conjugating $x^{i}$ by $x^{14}$, $$x^{14}x^{i}yx = x^{14 +i}yx = x^{28+i}y = x^{13+i}y \neq x^{i}y$$
Thus, the subgroups H of orders $3, 5, 15,$ can't contain an element $x^{i}y$, because if they did, we would have $\langle x^{i}y\rangle \subseteq H$ which is not possible because $2 \nmid 3, 5, 15$. Hence, the subgroups of orders $3, 5, 15,$ are the cyclic, normal, subgroups $\langle x \rangle, \langle x^3
\rangle, \langle x^{5} \rangle$.

My question is what about the subgroups of order $6$; $2$ **does** divide $6$, so the above reasoning does not work. Is $6$ a normal subgroup or not? why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subgroup of order 6 cannot be cyclic, as $D_{15}$ has no elements of order 6. Thus, it must be isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_3$, so must be generated by some elements $a,b$, of orders $2$ and $3$ respectively.

Now, the elements of $D_{15}$ of order $3$ are precisely $x^5$ and $x^{10}$ (so both must be in our subgroup), while the elements of order $2$ are precisely the $x^ay$. Thus, our subgroup must be of the form $G_a = \{1,x^{5}, x^{10}, x^ay,x^{5+a}y, x^{10+a}y\}$ for some integer $a$.

Now, we simply note that $xG_ax^{-1}$ contains $x^{a+1}yx^{-1} = x^{a+2}y$, which does not lie in $G_a$, hence $xG_ax^{-1}\neq G_a$, so $G_a$ is not normal in $D_{15}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a full classification of all normal subgroups of dihedral groups. Just check the case $n=15$.

[Normal subgroups of dihedral groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484828/normal-subgroups-of-dihedral-groups)

More precisely: For $n$ odd, the normal subgroups are given by $D_n$ and $\langle R^d \rangle$ for all divisors $d\mid n$. The groups $\langle R^d \rangle$ have index $2d$, so index $5$ for $n=15$ is impossible. So there is no normal subgroup of order
$\frac{30}{5}=6$.

Comment: Why is it that $d|n$?

Comment: Because $\langle R^d\rangle $ has order $n/d$, see subgroups of cyclic groups and Lagrange.

Comment: I'm sorry Sir but I'm missing the part why $\left<R^d\right>$ is a normal subgroup for $D_n$. Please enlighten me about the matter. Thank you very much.

Comment: Click on the link, then on K. Conrad's notes about this. They are most enlightening!