# The $221$ groups of order $|G| = 400$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, groups-enumeration

A book of John Conway suggests there are **221** groups of order $|G| = 400$.  How do I go about finding these.  Commutative groups with $ab = ba$ can be listed very easily:

- $\mathbb{Z}/400\mathbb{Z}$
- $\mathbb{Z}/200\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$
- $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z}$
- ...

There are **[207](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_400)** super-solvable groups of order $|G| = 400$ How do we list some of them?

$$ 1 \leq H_0 \leq H_1 \leq H_2 \leq \dots \leq H_n = G $$

here $H_i \vartriangleleft G$  and $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is [cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group).   This could be a great way to explain the difference between [nilpotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group) and [solvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group) groups.  Some discussion [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/subgpseries2.pdf) however I will put in the tag [representation-theory](/questions/tagged/representation-theory) which includes (for example) matrix representation or permutation representations.

There are **28** nilpotent groups of order $|G| = 400$.

---

[image]

---

I haven't used `GAP` the question would be how does the computer program find such objects?  Here's some of what it found:

- $G = (C_5 \ltimes Q_8 ) \times D_{10}$
- $G = (C_5 \ltimes C_5) \ltimes (C_4 \times C_4) $
- $G = C_2 \times ((C_5 \times C_5) \ltimes C_8)$

These names or descriptions leave it upon us to say what these symmetries actually look like.

- Example, $D_{10}$ is the [dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) or the symmetry group of a [10-gon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecagon)
- Also $D_{10} = C_{10} \ltimes C_2 $ , see also [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484828/normal-subgroups-of-dihedral-groups?rq=1)] .
- $C_n \simeq \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is the [cyclic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) .

Comment: Pithy but partly-accurate answer: https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/SmallGrp/doc/chap1.html . Though in all seriousness, the references there are probably going to be your best hope; since $|G|=p^4q^2$ it shouldn't be _too_ terrible to analyze the cases.

Comment: Even with computer help, just going through the list of results.

Comment: Any particular reason you're interested in $|G|=400$ particularly? $|G|=100$ has few enough candidates to be relatively straightforwardly enumerable, and $|G|=200$ has a quarter as many groups as 400 does, while still having non-trivial members in most of the categories (e.g. nilpotent but not abelian, solvable but not supersolvable, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [SmallGrp](http://gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/SmallGrp/doc/chap1.html) package for **GAP** and the function `StructureDescription` you can get some insight into the structure of the groups of order 400. See [the documentation](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X87BF1B887C91CA2E) for how to interpret these strings, e.g. a colon `:` denotes a semidirect product.

```
G := AllSmallGroups(400);;
List(G, g -> StructureDescription(g));
[ "C25 : C16", "C400", "C25 : C16", "C25 : Q16", "C8 x D50",
  "C25 : (C8 : C2)", "C25 : QD16", "D400", "C2 x (C25 : C8)",
  "C25 : (C8 : C2)", "C4 x (C25 : C4)", "C25 : (C4 : C4)",
  "C25 : (C4 : C4)", "C25 : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "C25 : QD16", "C25 : D16",
  "C25 : Q16", "C25 : QD16", "C25 : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "C100 x C4",
  "C25 x ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "C25 x (C4 : C4)", "C200 x C2",
  "C25 x (C8 : C2)", "C25 x D16", "C25 x QD16", "C25 x Q16",
  "C25 : (C8 x C2)", "C25 : (C8 : C2)", "C4 x (C25 : C4)",
  "C25 : (C4 : C4)", "C2 x (C25 : C8)", "C25 : (C8 : C2)",
  "C25 : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "C2 x (C25 : Q8)", "C2 x C4 x D50",
  "C2 x D200", "C25 : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "D8 x D50",
  "C25 : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "Q8 x D50", "C25 : ((C4 x C2) : C2)",
  "C2 x C2 x (C25 : C4)", "C2 x (C25 : D8)", "C100 x C2 x C2", "C50 x D8",
  "C50 x Q8", "C25 x ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "C5 x (C5 : C16)",
  "(C5 x C5) : C16", "C80 x C5", "(C2 x C2 x C2 x C2) : C25",
  "C2 x C2 x (C25 : C4)", "C2 x C2 x C2 x D50", "C50 x C2 x C2 x C2",
  "C5 x (C5 : C16)", "(C5 x C5) : C16", "(C5 x C5) : C16",
  "(C5 x C5) : C16", "(C5 : C8) x D10", "(C5 x C5) : (C8 x C2)",
  "(C5 x C5) : (C8 : C2)", "(C5 x C5) : (C8 : C2)", "(C5 x C5) : D16",
  "(C5 x C5) : D16", "(C5 x C5) : QD16", "(C5 x C5) : QD16",
  "(C5 x C5) : QD16", "(C5 x C5) : Q16", "(C5 x C5) : Q16",
  "(C5 : C4) x (C5 : C4)", "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)",
  "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "(C5 x C5) : (C4 : C4)",
  "(C5 x C5) : (C4 : C4)", "C40 x D10", "C5 x (C40 : C2)",
  "C5 x (C40 : C2)", "C5 x D80", "C5 x (C5 : Q16)", "C10 x (C5 : C8)",
  "C5 x ((C5 : C8) : C2)", "C20 x (C5 : C4)", "C5 x ((C5 : C4) : C4)",
  "C5 x (C20 : C4)", "C5 x ((C20 x C2) : C2)", "C5 x ((C5 x D8) : C2)",
  "C5 x ((C5 : Q8) : C2)", "C5 x ((C5 x Q8) : C2)", "C5 x (C5 : Q16)",
  "C5 x ((C10 x C2) : C4)", "C8 x ((C5 x C5) : C2)",
  "(C5 x C5) : (C8 : C2)", "(C5 x C5) : QD16", "(C5 x C5) : D16",
  "(C5 x C5) : Q16", "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : C8)", "(C5 x C5) : (C8 : C2)",
  "C4 x ((C5 x C5) : C4)", "(C5 x C5) : (C4 : C4)",
  "(C5 x C5) : (C4 : C4)", "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)",
  "(C5 x C5) : D16", "(C5 x C5) : QD16", "(C5 x C5) : QD16",
  "(C5 x C5) : Q16", "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "C20 x C20",
  "C5 x C5 x ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "C5 x C5 x (C4 : C4)", "C40 x C10",
  "C5 x C5 x (C8 : C2)", "C5 x C5 x D16", "C5 x C5 x QD16",
  "C5 x C5 x Q16", "(C5 x C5) : C16", "(C5 : C4) x (C5 : C4)",
  "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "(C5 x C5) : (C4 : C4)",
  "D10 x (C5 : C8)", "(C5 x C5) : (C8 x C2)", "(C5 x C5) : (C8 : C2)",
  "(C5 x C5) : (C8 : C2)", "(C5 x C5) : (C4 x C4)",
  "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "(C5 x C5) : (C4 : C4)",
  "(C5 x C5) : (C8 x C2)", "(C5 x C5) : (C8 : C2)",
  "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "(C5 x C5) : (C4 : C4)",
  "(C5 x C5) : D16", "(C5 x C5) : QD16", "(C5 x C5) : Q16",
  "(C5 x C5) : (C4 : C4)", "C5 x (C5 : (C8 x C2))",
  "C5 x ((C5 : C8) : C2)", "C20 x (C5 : C4)", "C5 x (C20 : C4)",
  "C10 x (C5 : C8)", "C5 x ((C5 : C8) : C2)", "C5 x ((C10 x C2) : C4)",
  "(C5 x C5) : (C8 x C2)", "(C5 x C5) : (C8 : C2)",
  "C4 x ((C5 x C5) : C4)", "(C5 x C5) : (C4 : C4)",
  "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : C8)", "(C5 x C5) : (C8 : C2)",
  "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "(C5 x C5) : (C8 x C2)",
  "(C5 x C5) : (C8 : C2)", "C4 x ((C5 x C5) : C4)",
  "(C5 x C5) : (C4 : C4)", "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : C8)",
  "(C5 x C5) : (C8 : C2)", "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)",
  "(C5 x C5) : (C8 x C2)", "(C5 x C5) : (C8 : C2)",
  "C4 x ((C5 x C5) : C4)", "(C5 x C5) : (C4 : C4)",
  "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : C8)", "(C5 x C5) : (C8 : C2)",
  "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "(C5 : Q8) x D10",
  "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)",
  "(C5 x C5) : (C2 x Q8)", "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)",
  "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "C4 x D10 x D10", "D40 x D10",
  "(C5 x C5) : (C2 x D8)", "C2 x ((C5 : C4) x D10)",
  "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)",
  "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : (C4 x C2))", "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : D8)",
  "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : D8)", "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : Q8)",
  "((C10 x C2) : C2) x D10", "(C5 x C5) : (C2 x D8)", "C10 x (C5 : Q8)",
  "C2 x C20 x D10", "C10 x D40", "C5 x ((C20 x C2) : C2)", "C5 x D8 x D10",
  "C5 x ((C4 x D10) : C2)", "C5 x Q8 x D10", "C5 x ((C4 x D10) : C2)",
  "C2 x C10 x (C5 : C4)", "C10 x ((C10 x C2) : C2)",
  "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : Q8)", "C2 x C4 x ((C5 x C5) : C2)",
  "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : D8)", "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)",
  "D8 x ((C5 x C5) : C2)", "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)",
  "Q8 x ((C5 x C5) : C2)", "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)",
  "C2 x C2 x ((C5 x C5) : C4)", "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : D8)", "C20 x C10 x C2",
  "C5 x C10 x D8", "C5 x C10 x Q8", "C5 x C5 x ((C4 x C2) : C2)",
  "(C5 : C4) x (C5 : C4)", "(C5 x C5) : (C8 : C2)",
  "(C5 x C5) : ((C4 x C2) : C2)", "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : C8)",
  "C2 x (D10 x (C5 : C4))", "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : (C4 x C2))",
  "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : D8)", "C2 x ((C5 x C5) : Q8)",
  "C5 x ((C2 x C2 x C2 x C2) : C5)", "C2 x C10 x (C5 : C4)",
  "C2 x C2 x ((C5 x C5) : C4)", "C2 x C2 x ((C5 x C5) : C4)",
  "C2 x C2 x ((C5 x C5) : C4)", "C2 x C2 x D10 x D10",
  "C2 x C2 x C10 x D10", "C2 x C2 x C2 x ((C5 x C5) : C2)",
  "C10 x C10 x C2 x C2" ]
```

Comment: the best we can do is type in a computer and look around?

Comment: No but I hoped the results could help you with the intuition required to come up with the theory. Unfortunately I don’t feel well qualified to do the theory part.

Comment: it's a great starting point...

Comment: If you're interested in the **best** we can do, your question is much, much too broad for math.stackexchange.

Comment: Just to add that SmallGrp is a database, while to construct them almost "from scratch" you can use the [GrpConst](https://gap-packages.github.io/grpconst/) package. After `LoadPackage("grpconst");`, enter `l:=ConstructAllGroups(400);Length(l);` - took only 3 seconds to get the result.